# ansible mysql replication fails to change master to due to 'Sending passwords in plain text without SSL/TLS is extremely insecure.'

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, ansible

I'm setting up mysql replication with ansible mysql replication module, but got a failure:

```
TASK: [mysql | change the master in slave to start the replication] ***********
failed: [mysql-master-1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
invalid output was: Change master
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1414844287.9-261276925072204/mysql_replication", line 1714, in <module>
main()
File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1414844287.9-261276925072204/mysql_replication", line 351, in main
changemaster(cursor,chm)
File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1414844287.9-261276925072204/mysql_replication", line 164, in changemaster
cursor.execute("CHANGE MASTER TO " + SQLPARAM)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 175, in execute
if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 89, in _warning_check
warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Sending passwords in plain text without SSL/TLS is extremely insecure.
```

The infrastrucure:

```
target servers:centos 6.4
ansible: 1.7.2
mysqldb:5.6.12-1.el6.x86_64
```

The playbook:

```
- name: change the master in slave to start the replication
  mysql_replication: >
    mode=changemaster
    master_host={{ mysql_master_host }}
    master_user={{ mysql_repl_user }}
    master_password={{ mysql_repl_password }}
```

I tried setting the replication manually, it worked:

```
mysql>change master to
     >master_host='mysql-master-1'
     >master_user='repl_user'
     >master_password='123456';
```

It seems like the mysqldb python module fails to parse the command, how can I fix this without using ssl replication?

**UPDATE**

I modified the source file of "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" by changing _defer_warning from False to True, issue fixed. But is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: Err, use TLS to connect to the master, as the message suggests?

Comment: @EJP thanks. But I've read several playbooks, they don't use TLS as well. I'm just wondering what did I do wrong.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find the fix?

Comment: @blacksoul Please the update part, sorry I don't find any further fix by now. Please add an answer if you find one :-)

Comment: I'm just using `ignore_errors` to allow continue the playbook, but the errors still appearing

Answer (score 0):

Updated replication module with two added options:

1. `warnings_filtered` - which types of warnings should be muted (all,
   warnings, none). Taken from [here](http://ops.kinja.com/mysql_replciation-ansible-module-update-1525041688).
2. `master_delay` - same as mysql variable.

https://github.com/vbkunin/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/database/mysql/mysql_replication.py

Replace this: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/extras/database/mysql/mysql_replication.py`.